# Spring boot, output json http requestbody before serialize

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, httprequest

Spring boot will do the following step when receives a http request.

1.Read json http requestbody First

2.Then deserialized it to `@RequestBody` object.

```
// Json Data Mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(request)
```

I can output the json body by use ObjectMapper, but it will be more effective if I can output the json body directly before it is deserialized to object.

Is it possible to output the json request body before spring boot deserializes it to object?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
@RequestMapping("/...")
public Bar findBar(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    // ...
}
```

you could do this:

```
@RequestMapping("/...")
public Bar findBar(Reader reader) {
    String json = reader.read..( );
    Foo foo = objectMapper.read( ... );
}
```

But I don't think there is a way to get **both the de-serialized object and the raw response**. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to output the raw request body in log and use @RequestBody as well. Is it possible?

Comment: @Yuu as I mentioned, **I don't think there is a way to get both**. Either you get the object and then serialize, or you get the raw request and de-serialize.

Comment: @Yuu you are welcome. You can accept the answer using the tick next to it, if you feel it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to JSON as a string object,

```
@RequestMapping("/...")
public Bar findBar(@RequestBody("json") String json) {
    // ...
}
```

above snippet will give you JSON string as an output. Now if you want to convert it into object then you can do manually using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can output the raw request output. But @Valid annotation seems doesn't work if I used the way you recomanded.

Comment: I have added some of my codes. Thank you for your confirmation.

Comment: This is not working anymore as Spring says `can't find symbol value`

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Bar getBar(@Valid @RequestBody String jsonBody){
    System.out.println("data:" + jsonBody);
}

public class BarRequestEntity{

    // AuthenticationKey
    @NotBlank(message = "id {error.empty}")
    private String id;
}
```

I was using `@Valid` to check the request parameter.

Comment: you are using @@valid wrong way. You need to define user defined object with @@valid

Comment: Can you show me an example, where do I supposed to put @valid?

Comment: if you want an output as JSON data then you need to do using objectmapper or GSON library.

Comment: Yes, I can output the json by the way you methoned, but I can not use @valid now...

Comment: you have to mention valid annotation and RequestBody Foo foo , after that you need to convert foo object into json manually using objectmapper or GSON lib.